# Using the transform property and getting the element to center properly at the same time

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transform

I am attempting to get two images to transform into position. One from the left, the other from the right. This was working fine, but then I attempted to center the images within their parent element. Now both images are coming in from the top diagonally from left to right.

Here is what the containers look like:

[image]

I am wanting the left image (that needs to be centered in the left container) to come in from the left and vise versa for the right.

Sliding in:

[image]

To final position:

[image]

What am I doing wrong that isn't allowing for my images to come in from their respective side and then center in their parent element?\

```js
function packageImg() {
  $('#calendar-img').addClass("fadeDisplay");
  $('#tp-img').addClass("fadeDisplay");
};
setTimeout(packageImg, 300);
```

```css
.total-center {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

#product-img-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.package-img {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

#calendar-wrap,
#tp-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#calendar-img {
  margin-right: -30px;
}

#tp-img {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#calendar-img.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}

#tp-img.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product-img-wrap">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div id="calendar-wrap">
      <img src="images/RealtorCalendar.jpg" alt="Real Estate Calendar Package" class="package-img total-center" id="calendar-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div id="tp-wrap">
      <img src="images/REtp.jpg" alt="Real Estate Calendar Package" class="package-img total-center" id="tp-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mmk7ngw7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already used `translate()` to center them in the first place, you have to start from `translateX( -50% )` when you do the transition, so the transform needs to look like this

```
#calendar-img.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX( calc(-50% + 30px) );
}

#tp-img.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX( calc(-50% - 30px) );
}
```

*Side note, always put the non-prefixed properties last, and assign which values the transition should use, `transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;`*

```js
function packageImg() {
  $('#calendar-img').addClass("fadeDisplay");
  $('#tp-img').addClass("fadeDisplay");
};
setTimeout(packageImg, 300);
```

```css
.total-center {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

#product-img-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.package-img {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
}

#calendar-wrap,
#tp-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#calendar-img {
  margin-right: -30px;
}

#tp-img {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#calendar-img.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX( calc(-50% + 30px) );
}

#tp-img.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX( calc(-50% - 30px) );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="product-img-wrap">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div id="calendar-wrap">
      <img src="images/RealtorCalendar.jpg" alt="Real Estate Calendar Package" class="package-img total-center" id="calendar-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div id="tp-wrap">
      <img src="images/REtp.jpg" alt="Real Estate Calendar Package" class="package-img total-center" id="tp-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!